# How can I add find the gain from root locus and poles?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I try to find the P-gain from a root locus plot where I know the poles.
Assume that we got a reference model:

$$G(s) = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2 }$$

Where $\zeta$ and $\omega_n$ are known.

Let's say I want to find the gain for that reference model, to implement into another controller for another model.

Then I compute the poles (s):
$$ 0 = s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2 $$

If I want to compute the gain, I need to use this formula:

$$K_p = abs\left [\frac{den(p)}{num(p)}\right ]$$

Link: http://faculty.petra.ac.id/resmana/private/matlab-help/toolbox/control/rlocfind.html

**Question:**

If I got a single row pole such as $p = a + bi$ this will work. But how would I do if I got multiple poles?

Comment: Can you check the equation for your reference model? It is shown as a first order model, but expressed in a form typically reserved for a second order model. Note the second order model is in the form $G(s)=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2 \zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2}$, which is different from your model.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Done! Have edited now.

Comment: Also, do you want to calculate the DC gain of the plant, or the Proportional gain, where the plant is used in a (possibly unity) feedback system with a proportional controller?

Comment: @WinterSoldier I don't know if DC gain would help me.

Comment: In general, let's assume that the plant is $G(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)}=\frac{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}$, where $m \le n$. If we use this plant with a proportional controller of gain $K$, in a unity feedback system, then the characteristic equation is $1+KG(s)=1+K\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}=0 \Rightarrow K = -\frac{D(s)}{N(s)}$ for $K \ge 0$ since we assume negative feedback. Therefore, for a given value of $s=s_0$, $K=\left. -\frac{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}\right|_{s=s_0}$.

Comment: @WinterSoldier So If I find the DC-gain, I can use that into my P-controller?

Comment: Let's assume you want to use a proportional controller with $G(s)$ and unity feedback closed loop system. Then one method is to determine the desired closed loop pole location that will give the desired rise time, settling time, etc. Then to find the value of $K$ required, simply substitute this value of $s=s_0$ into the equation for $K$ above. Note: In your case, the poles are complex conjugate since the coefficients of the polynomial are real. But, I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: Finally, if you provide me with the exact value of $G(s)$ that you intend to use, then I can provide you with an example to make it more clear.

Comment: Why not post an answer? @WinterSoldier

Comment: @WinterSoldier You have understand my question perfectly. If you answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an answer:
Let's consider a SISO system, where the transfer function of the plant is given by $G(s)$, and the feedback gain, is $H(s)$. Let's also assume that only a proportional control with gain $K$ is to be used.
Then, the closed loop transfer function is given by:
$$\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{KG(s)}{1+KG(s)H(s)}$$
where $Y(s)$ is the plant output, and $R(s)$ is the reference signal input. The characteristic equation is $1+KG(s)H(s)$.

As you know, the Root Locus method plots the roots of the characteristic equation - which are the closed loop poles - as a function of gain $K$, where $K \ge 0$, assuming negative feedback is required. Now for unity feedback, $H(s)=1$, and thus the characteristic equation is given by $1+KG(s)=0$.

Now, let the plant transfer function be given as $$G(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)}=\frac{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}$$ where $m \le n$.

In this case, the characteristic (or closed loop poles) equation is given by:
$$\therefore 1+ KG(s)=1+ K\frac{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}$$
$$\Rightarrow K=-\frac{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}$$

Finally, since the characteristic equation has real coefficients, any complex poles will occur as conjugate pairs - which is why the Root locus plot is typically symmetric about the real axis.

Hence, once the desired closed loop pole, $s_0$ is calculated based on the required control system performance criteria (rise time, maximum overshoot, settling time, etc.), the desired value of the (proportional) control gain can be found as:

$$K=\left. -\frac{(s+p_0)(s+p_1)...(s+p_n)}{(s+z_0)(s+z_1)...(s+z_m)}\right|_{s=s_0}$$

Again, since negative feedback is used, we want values of $K \ge 0$.

It should be noted that for a second order realizable plant with proportional gain and unity feedback, the closed loop transfer function will also be of second order, with the characteristic equation in the form $s^2 + 2\zeta \omega_n s + \omega_n^2$.